# SQL update 1 table from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I need some help with creating an update query. For example I have

```
select:(T1- table 1, T2- tables 2, Z1 -column from table 1, Z2 Column from table 2 etc)

Select * from T1,T2 where X1=X2 and Y1=Y2 and Z1=Z2 and Datea>=20160601 and Dateb<20160720 and B1=2 and C1=5 and D1=10 and E2 in (A+,A-, 22,33,44)
```

Now I want to write an `update` which uses parameters

```
from where
update T1 set F1, G1 where
```

How to write the correct conditions?

Comment: You could perform a subquery within your update?

Comment: FOR EXAMPLE..UPDATE TABLENAME SET F1 = (SELECT * FROM)

Comment: sorry i wrote it wrong .Update  should be like update T1 set F1=10, G1=50 where

Comment: You still could use subquery within each of the SET statements to get you that value?

Comment: Solution might be update T1 set F1=10, G1=50 where exist (Select * from T1,T2 
where X1=X2 and Y1=Y2 and Z1=Z2 
    and Datea>=20160601 
    and Dateb<20160720 
    and B1=2 
    and C1=5 
    and D1=10 and E2 in (A+,A-, 22,33,44))

Comment: My solution didnt worked correctly it updated the whole base :/

Comment: did the below answer work?

Comment: Select * from T1,T2 where exist ( (Select F1, G1 
             from T1,T2 where X1=X2 
             and Y1=Y2 and Z1=Z2 
             and Datea>=20160601 
             and Dateb<20160720 
             and B1=2 
             and C1=5 
             and D1=10 
             and E2 in (A+,A-, 22,33,44))

Didn't worked.

Comment: look at the answer

Comment: When I Select * from T1,T2 where exist ( (Select F1, G1 from T1,T2 where X1=X2 and Y1=Y2 and Z1=Z2 and Datea>=20160601 and Dateb<20160720 and B1=2 and C1=5 and D1=10 and E2 in (A+,A-, 22,33,44)) it gives me wrong result. :(

Comment: what is your query trying to do?

Comment: I want to select those rows i want to update secondly  but it shows for example not only  B1=2 but all records.

Comment: Remove the c1=5  iin the where clause and try it?. If you only want for B1, then why have you got c1 =5 and D1=10?

Comment: I want all rows which meet all these conditions X1=X2 and Y1=Y2 and Z1=Z2 and Datea>=20160601 and Dateb<20160720 and B1=2 and C1=5 and D1=10 and E2 in (A+,A-, 22,33,44)

Comment: yes but what happenes if you only have B1 =2

Answer (score 0):

```
update T1 set F1=10, G1=50 
where exist (Select F1, G1 
             from T1,T2 where X1=X2 
             and Y1=Y2 and Z1=Z2 
             and Datea>=20160601 
             and Dateb<20160720 
             and B1=2 
             and C1=5 
             and D1=10 
             and E2 in (A+,A-, 22,33,44))
```

Youi have to select the columns, that needs to be updated in the select clause.

Also try to run the select statement first, to see if you are getting the results you want